# window.top.location.href is not working in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I have a web page `http://example.com/search/` where we have a link, on click of that link we are opening an iframe in popup using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) jQuery plugin.

Then that iframe have a `<button>` element on click of that we are redirecting user to another web page. As it is inside an iframe so we are using following code:

```
mcbcarea.on("click", ".btnBook", function(){
   window.top.location.href = $(this).data("href");
});
```

This code is working in all browsers, and even in all IE except in new IE Edge browser.

Currently it is not opening new button url, instead it is simply refreshing the parent page: `http://example.com/search/`

Can anyone please check and help here?

Comment: Have you tried to replace `window.top.location.href` with `window.location.href`?

Comment: Ah ok. Can you destroy and recreate your iframe?

Comment: @erikscandola I tried to use "window.location.href" but this opens the url in iframe itself, not in the parent window. Sorry not getting your last comment, what to do here?

Comment: Even I tried to put a function in parent window JS file, and then call it from the iframe and set url etc. but that also not worked, still it is opening the same /search url.

Comment: What I mean is un destroy your iframe and then recreate it with the new URL

Comment: But what it will do then? Because if we can set the top window url to somewhere else, then iframe will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: Check the console, you may have a "Permission denied" exception. Edge is tricky with iframes.

Comment: You can do what I say only for edge since in other browser works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**change code:**

```
window.top.location.href = $(this).data("href");
```

**To**

top.window.location.href = $(this).data("href");